# Less Specific CSS Selectors Overriding Styles

Tags: css

I thought I understood how CSS selectors worked, the more specific selectors override less specific selectors:

`#ids > .classes > element > :attribute`

I have an element that gets a default `box-shadow` color with `input:focus` as its selector.  When I add style to override that property, the default box-shadow color gets applied.  Ignore the horrible selectors for now, I was just trying to get it to work:

[image]

Am I missing something?  By all my understanding, the `box-shadow` with the `input:focus` selector should be overwritten.

Comment: Figured it out, the CSS preproccesser removed the comma between inset and normal `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box-shadow values had their commas stripped from the styles due to the preprocessor I'm using.  Changing how the box-shadow properties were being generated fixed the problem.